# Two similar PHP forms but only one is working

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, email

I'm fairly new to responsive web design, so I found a template that I thought I could adapt to my needs. The front page has a "quick" (abbreviated) contact form and the contact page has a more complete contact form. Each page is html and the forms call to contact.php  on submit. The contact jQuery is contained in custom.js. I have been working locally on a MAMP server and get a correct response from contact.html on submission, "Email Sent Successfully."

```
<form id="contactform" class="row" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post">
    <fieldset class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="company" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only">Select Time</label>
            <select name="select_service" id="select_service" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="btn-white">
                <option value="">Select Time</option>
                <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
                <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only"> Select Budget</label>
            <select name="select_price" id="select_price" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="btn-white">
                <option value=""> Select Budget</option>
                <option value="undecided"> Undecided</option>
                <option value="$100 - $2000">$100 - $2,000</option>
                <option value="$2000 - $4000">$2,000 - $4,000</option>
                <option value="$4000 - $10000">$4,000 - $10,000</option>
                <option value="above $10000"> Above $10,000</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" rows="6" placeholder="How may we help you..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-radius btn-brd grd1 btn-block">Get Appointment</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

However, on index.html, the quick form fails to work. I discovered that the `action="contact.php"` was omitted. When it is added to the page, upon submission the URL changes to contact.php and the first error text is displayed, "Attention! You must enter your name.", this despite having populated all of the fields prior to submission. So, I found that the form ids in this version were incremented by one as in `id="contactform1"`. So I made these ids match the working form, but it still doesn't work.  This is my current revision:

```
<form id="contactform" class="row" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post">
    <fieldset class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="first_name1" id="first_name1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="last_name1" id="last_name1" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="email" name="email1" id="email1" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only">Select Time</label>
            <select name="select_service1" id="select_service1" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="btn-white">
                <option value="selecttime">Select Time</option>
                <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
                <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only">Select</label>
            <select name="select_price1" id="select_price1" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="btn-white">
                <option value="$100 - $2000">Advertising</option>
                <option value="$2000 - $4000">Marketing</option>
                <option value="$4000 - $10000">Profile</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-radius btn-brd grd1 btn-block">Get an Appointment</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I don't see a specific reference in either contact.php or the contact code in custom.js to contact.html that would prevent the form on index.html from working, and yet it doesn't. Can you shed some light as to why the form on one page would work while the form on the other fails?

Contact.php:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$first_name     = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name     = $_POST['last_name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$select_price   = $_POST['select_price'];
$select_service   = $_POST['select_service'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($first_name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
}  else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = "fymbscu@earthlink.net";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $first_name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $first_name. $first_name selected service of $select_service, their additional message is as follows. Customer max budge is $select_price, for this project." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $first_name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$first_name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Contact code from custom.js:

```
/* ==============================================
 CONTACT -->
 =============================================== */
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactform').submit(function () {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $("#message").slideUp(750, function () {
            $('#message').hide();
            $('#submit')
                .after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $.post(action, {
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                phone: $('#phone').val(),
                select_service: $('#select_service').val(),
                select_price: $('#select_price').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(),
                verify: $('#verify').val()
            },
                function (data) {
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        $(this).remove()
                    });
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if (data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
                }
            );
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Returning to the proof-of-concept idea I mentioned in the comments, I have tried replacing the form on index.html in it's entirety with the form from contact.html, ensuring that all of the references are identical and intact. This trial has failed to produce the success response on this revised page, so the identical code works in one instance and not the other. On the index page, the form "slides into position from the left." Maybe that action is creating the interference with the submission?

Here are URLs for a live demo of the original template files:
[index.html](https://html.design/demo/city_real_estate/index.html)

[contact.html](https://html.design/demo/city_real_estate/contact.html)

They represent the logic that I am working with and trying to fix. Hope this helps clarify my problem.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. What JavaScript? There's none in your question. What does that code actually do? When you changed all `id`'s and `name`'s, did you also change any JS/PHP code that uses those id's/names?

Comment: Do you try to send these two **different** forms with one (the same) PHP script? There are differences in field names and for 99.9% it won't work. You need to create another PHP script and work with sent form data separately.

Comment: @biesior  When I initially tried to test the forms, I saw that the only one that worked was the form on contact.html. I checked both the php and js files and didn't see any references that I felt would limit them in a way that they should only work with contact.html. As I noted above, the `action="contact.php"` was absent from the index.html form. I added it to that form on the assumption that I should get a response to confirm the form worked, a proof of concept. Now I am trying to trace back why I didn't get the success response that I got from the other form.

Comment: I did originally try to post the code for the php file as well as the javascript,  but my question was blocked as "spam." I am still very new to Stack Overflow and have been frustrated at every turn, for one thing or another. I will try to edit my question and include that code now.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson You are correct that I did not edit or alter any of the JS/PHP code, just some changes to the forms on the html pages. Since there is no database involved, I thought I could get a working test and then revise from there. I guess that was a bit short-sighted on my part?

Comment: If you change the name of a form element and doesn't change your PHP (and maybe JS, depending on implementation), it won't where to get the value. In PHP, you fetch a post value with: `$_POST['foo']`. If you change the name to `'foo2` in your form, then the PHP code won't find it since it's looking for `foo`. And if your JS also fetches those elements by name or id, it would have the same issue.